# Display data in a html table based on some restriction

Tags: php

$abc=array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8);

$xyz=array(a,b,c,d,e,f);

I want to retrieve data from above two arrays in a desired format (Actually those arrays are generated from database tables). The data will be displayed in html TABLE. I have used PHP MYSQL. The values may not be in a sequence as of example been displayed, but there is two distinct arrays. To make it more clear I want to say that the odd columns (starting from first column) will display the values of **array abc** and even will display the values of **array xyz**.
Please help me out. Thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: We cannot do your work. But at first, before I would do anything, I need to know something about how user data are processed. Is page reloaded after clicking on _Go_? Or is there any AJAX?

Comment: This question is unclear, because (for one) it doesn't describe the rules for this division into columns. Would just go on adding empty columns if $abc was much longer than $xyz? Also, is there a specific reason to have only 3 rows? Apart from that, this is a poor question for the reasons @Václav mentioned.

Comment: You're right that it may add empty columns if array size mismatch, but the logic is that if one array completes, another array will append from there. Actually this is a exam seat plan of an institution and they want automated generation of roll nos of students of different courses. e.g. Suppose student of physics will sit on row 1,3,5..... and chemistry on 2,4,6..... and if seat left in odd or even rows then biology will continue from there. I know its a critical logic though, but i have to make it happen. Other ideas are also appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a really interesting question. I think I found a solution.

```
function table (array $array1, array $array2, $splitIndex)
    {
    $rows = array ();
    $currentRow = 0;

    // Make sure $array1 is the bigger of them
    if (count ($array2) > count ($array1))
    {
        $arrayTemp = $array2;
        $array2 = $array1;
        $array1 = $arrayTemp;
    }

    // Loop over each element of the array
    foreach ($array1 as $index => $arrayValue)
    {
        $rows [$currentRow] [] = $arrayValue;
        if (isset ($array2 [$index]))
            $rows [$currentRow] [] = $array2 [$index];
        else
            $rows [$currentRow] [] = '';

        $currentRow = ($currentRow == $splitIndex ? 0 : $currentRow + 1);
    }
    $output = '<table>';

    // Loop over the rows
    foreach ($rows as $row)
    {
        $subOutput = '<tr>';

        // Loop over the columns in the rows
        foreach ($row as $element)
            $subOutput .='<td>'. $element .'</td>';

        $output .= $subOutput .'</tr>';
    }

    // Return the output altogether.
    return $output .'</table>';
}
```

Now you can use:

```
echo table ([ 'i', 'b', 'a', 'e', 'b' ], ['1', '2', '3'], 2);
```

The 2 indicates that it will split on every two rows, like it was 3 in your example.

Comment: Thanks Aron, its working according to my need, but is it possible to limit the number of rows and columns in a table such that it will display only those values that fit to the table. Also can I set the starting and ending range of the value in an array to be displayed. Hope you are clear. Thanks again for your help.

Comment: I have made some changes to the script. It's got a new syntax with more customization options now. https://gist.github.com/Xesau/66d74336d1b91f81ed44


Starting and Ending Range version: https://gist.github.com/Xesau/c78f5e72f53db228a00a

*Usage*:
    `echo keyValueTable (['a' => 'b'....], 0, array (), 0, ' ', $startIndex, $length);`

Comment: I am not able to call the function, the parameters I am passing results in blank, please give an example. Thank you

Comment: Please look at the default values in the source code. A major change to the original code is that now you have to send just a single array, instead of two. array_fill_keys () might work for you. I already gave an example code as you can see in my previous comment. Just make sure to use that single array and everything should be fine :)